# show confirmation modal dialog after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form and I need it to do 2 things once the submit button is clicked:

1. I need the form data to be processed in the acknowledge.php that I have created.
2. I need the modal dialog to display confirmation.

My form:

```
<form class="quote-form" method="post" action="acknowledge.php">

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Full Name</span>
      <input type="text" name="name">
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Email</span>
      <input type="email" name="email">
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Phone</span>
      <input type="number" name="phone">
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Nature of Enquiry</span>
      <select name="enquiry">
        <option selected>General Enquiry</option>
        <option>Logo Design</option>
        <option>Web Design</option>
        <option>Branding</option>
        <option>Social Media</option>
        <option>Email/Web Hosting</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Message</span>
      <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <button type="button" name="send">Get A Quote</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

I'm new to Javascript and AJAX but I have copied some code from some similar threads and tried to customize it to my site

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".quote-form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: $(".quote-form").serialize(),
    url: 'url',
    success: function(data) {
      $("#myModal").modal("show");
    }
  });
  return false;
  });
});
</script>

<!--Modal container-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content--> 
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">x</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the submit button is clicked nothing happens. Even the acknowledge.php does not execute. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post a "working" example in Jsfiddle? Also did you check your console and/or used a tool like Fiddler to check what is happening?

Comment: I have never used Fiddler before

Comment: @K.Mak please provide your CSS as well and see my answer so far

Answer (score 1):

you need to wrap your code in a **[document.ready()](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8m_SHiLTNAhXLsxQKHfaLAPUQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.jquery.com%2Fusing-jquery-core%2Fdocument-ready%2F&usg=AFQjCNExWbD0RBCnOOUMXHiJCRB_nNuJJw)** function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".quote-form").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                data: $(".quote-form").serialize(),
                url : 'url',
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#myModal").modal("show");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

you need to change the type of your button to `submit` like this

```
<button type="submit" name="send">Get A Quote</button>
```

Comment: Still nothing happens. Am I supposed to put this code at the bottom of the html or in the head maybe?

Comment: doesn't matter, either way it should work also you need to change the type of the button check the update

Answer (score 1):

A number of things that have been holding you up:

1. In your javascript, you have a trailing `});` right at the end.
2. Your `button` is doing nothing to trigger the submit event in the javascript. You should alter the button or use a proper submit input. Or use `type="submit"`.
3. You're not doing anything with `data` in your success callback. So when the modal opens, nothing else happens.
4. Your URL in the AJAX request is not set. You could use `this.action` to use the form's action URL here.

I've made some changes that you can preview in [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epfwfbyt/).

There are some parts of the fiddle that you should ignore, such as the ajax `url` and `data` options. Those should be something like:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: this.action,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    //...
  });
```

What we obviously do not know now is whether you have included your dependency scripts like jQuery and bootstrap into your page.

For example: `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` is the bootstrap javascript.

Make sure that jQuery is above bootstrap, or bootstrap will fail to load as it depends on jQuery. You may need to use the bootstrap CSS as well.

Lastly, you need to check that your `action` in the form is the correct URL, and that the data in your form that is sent is processed and `echo`ed back as HTML.

You will also want to go to the bootstrap documentation, get a better example of the modal, and check out the forms area to spruce up this form.

You could use developer tools in your browser and note any errors thrown by javascript in the console if you still have problems. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>).

*You didn't need to wrap anything in a document ready.*

Answer (score 0):

You doing two things wrong

First you need to wrap your code with document.ready

```
$(function(){

});
```

Then you need to fix your url

```
var form = $(".quote-form");
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    data: form .serialize(),
    url : form.attr('action'),
    success: function(data) {
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert(errorThrown);
    }

});
```

Comment: I made those changes and nothing happens still. The modal dialog does not display

Comment: maybe your ajax is not successful, add error callback and check for any errors. Check my edit.